# DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library from nodejs code

Tags: node.js, oracle, express

I'm trying to establish a simple database connection to run a sql query from an express/node app and when I hit my endpoint, I see the following error:

```
message:"DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "The specified module could not be found". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#windows for help\nNode-oracledb installation instructions: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html\nYou must have 64-bit Oracle client libraries in your PATH environment variable.\nIf you do not have Oracle Database on this computer, then install the Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package from\nhttp://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html\nA Microsoft Visual Studio Redistributable suitable for your Oracle client library version must be available.
```

All i'm doing from my code is

```
result = connection.execute(sql);
```

I created a small little express application and I am trying to invoke a url on http://localhost:3000/url which does a simple select * from table query. I am not sure why I would need any kind of Oracle installation. Here is my full code:

```
var express = require("express");
var expressapp = express();
var oracledb = require('oracledb');
var dbConfig = require('./dbconfig.js');

expressapp.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server running on port 3000");
});

expressapp.get("/url", (req, res, next) => {

let connection, result, sql;

sql = `SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE FNAME = 'TEST'`;
binds = {};

// For a complete list of options see the documentation.
options = {
  outFormat: oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT   // query result format
  // extendedMetaData: true,   // get extra metadata
  // fetchArraySize: 100       // internal buffer allocation size for tuning
};

connection = oracledb.getConnection({
    user          : "xxxxx",
    password      : "xxxxx",
    connectString : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  });

result = connection.execute(sql);
console.log("Response: ");
console.log(result);

res.json(result);
});
```

Comment: Have a look at
https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#oracleclientloadingwindows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The oracle 'oracledb' driver ([node-oracledb](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb)) [requires the Oracle client](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html#quickstart) to connect to the database.

You can find the Oracle client at https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client.html

Answer (score 1):

The solution is:

```
oracledb.initOracleClient({libDir: 'D:\\Oracle\\instantclient_19_17'});
```

Here the path(D:\Oracle\instantclient_19_17) we have mentioned is pointing to ***folder*** containing Oracle Instant Client's content.

Oracle Instant Client Download (is dependent on OS & 32 OR 64-bit System etc) which one is suitable.

Ex: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html

We downloaded just the ***Basic Package*** from this link for our ***Windows 64-bit System***.

After download please ***make sure*** that download should have these files ***else this issue will not resolve*** and we will simply try many things instead of fixing the actual issue.

[image]

Once you have this download in place then just ***pointing*** to it using the above mentioned code will resolve the issue.

You can refer the following links for more detials:

https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#oracleclientloadingwindows

https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/introduction.html#getstarted

Comment: One note for readers: this solution works on Windows and macOS, but won't work on Linux.  The documentation has details.